# Make text fit in table cell when scaling, adapting font-size

Tags: text, responsive-design, font-size, css-tables, tablecell

I have a table which adapts its total width when the width of the screen is changed. Unfortunately this results in text overflowing the table cell because it's too large. I have tried the vw and vh units but that makes the text too small too fast. It should "just fit" in the table cell.

Do you have any ideas how that's possible or thoughts about how I possibly can change my table to function better?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="fit">
<div>some text</div>
</div>
```

With a fixed size

```
#fitin {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 1em;
}
```

This JavaScript will do the job.

```
$(function() {
while( $('#fitin div').height() > $('#fitin').height() ) {
    $('#fitin div').css('font-size', (parseInt($('#fitin div').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px" );
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[FitText](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js) is an easy solution if it's a good fit for your project, here's a working example
http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/lDBvc

Sometimes you have to play with the compressor setting to tweak the results for the specifics of your text and the space available ( eg ....fitText(1.2))

Hoe this helps!